# Absolute positioning of div while maintaining page layout

Tags: html, css

I'm constructing a blog page for my website that is split into two columns. Column 1 `.col_1` (red) is a fixed width and Column 2 `.col_2` (blue) occupies the remaining space. Column 2 contains a rich text block `.rich_text` (green) with all blog headings, text and content contained within a maximum width.

I want all tables in the `.rich_text` block to extend beyond the left and right borders of `.rich_text` and touch the edges of `.page_body`, so that they stretch the entire width of `.page_body`. I can achieve this effect by setting `position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px;` as demonstrated in `.table_container_abs`, but this also results in the table overlapping content in `.rich_text` as it has absolute positioning.

Please see this embedded example of my current page layout. **Without using JS if necessary, how can I extend these tables to the edges of `.page_body` while maintaining their interaction with other elements in the rich text block?**

```css
.page_body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative
}

.col_1 {
  width: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #FFC9C9
}

.col_2 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  background-color: #C9DEFF
}

.rich_text {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #F0FFFA
}

.table_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #656565
}

.table_container_abs {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #656565
}
```

```html
<div class='page_body'>
  <div class='col_1'>Post navigation</div>
  <div class='col_2'>
    <div class='rich_text'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      <br><br>
      <div class='table_container'>Table</div>
      <br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
      <br>
      <div class='table_container_abs'>Absolute table</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. "I want all tables /.../ to extend beyond... /.../ but this also results in the table overlapping..." – So you want them to overlap (extend), but you don't want them to overlap? Seems like it's the default thinking that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve no text overlapping with the usage of absolute position property, but you can achieve what you want with the following steps:

1 - Move `table_container_abs` div to be outside `col_2` and to be the last direct child of `page_body` div.

2 - Give `table_container_abs` class `flex: 0 0 100%;` property and remove the absolute position, top  and left properties.

3 - Give  `page_body` class `flex-wrap: wrap;` so that parent will wrap the contained boxes within.

With this way you save your boxes from any overlapping , enjoy !

Comment: This doesn’t address the issue. The problem is that we are trying to enable the table to dynamically resize **within** the rich text block, not before or after it.